# What EventClass is a TRUNCATE?

Tags: sql-server, truncate

Trying to query why all records are being deleted from a table, nothing comes up with eventclass = 47 (delete) - perhaps its a truncate so I want to query it in the trace file thanks

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but you might be able to verify on the log if a truncate was issued by using [fn_dblog](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/): `SELECT [Current LSN],
    [Operation],
    [Context],
    [Transaction ID],
    [Description]
FROM fn_dblog (NULL, NULL)
WHERE Description LIKE '%TRUNCATE%';`

Comment: 47 is `Object:Deleted` [Indicates that an object has been deleted, such as in DROP INDEX and DROP TABLE statements.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-trace-setevent-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) so this wouldn't be expected to capture `DELETE` anyway